# Convert spaces to table cells

Tags: html, powershell

I have a shell command I am trying to format nicely into HTML using Powershell.

Here is what the shell output produces:

[image]

I am using the following code to parse that section out of the shell command and insert `<br>` tag to create an HTML friendly output.

```
$VPLEX = plink 192.168.10.10 -l admin -pw password ./health
$regex = '(?ms)Clusters:(.+?)Meta Data:'
$VPLEX = $VPLEX -join "<br>"
$VPLEX_Clusters = [regex]::Matches($VPLEX,$regex) | foreach {$_.groups[1].value}
```

I then attempted to use this code to swap the spaces for something else, I was thinking of a tab originally (like a word processor would handle it) but right now am using 4 `&nbsp;`.

```
$VPLEX_Clusters = $VPLEX_Clusters -replace ' {1,}', "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"

$VPLEX_Clusters | Out-File F:\Scripts\healthcheck\test.html
```

This produces the following:

[image]

As you can see the text is not aligning vertically making it difficult to understand. I'm thinking maybe I can convert the spaces to new table cells instead and parse out each line individually? I'm really not too sure though, I'm hoping there is an easier way translate the shell output to HTML without losing the original spacing.

*EDIT*
(new code, aligned but only uses the first line)

```
$VPLEX = plink 192.168.10.10 -l admin -pw password ./health
$regex = '(?ms)Clusters:(.+?)Meta Data:'
$VPLEX = $VPLEX -join "`r`n"
$VPLEX_Clusters = [regex]::Matches($VPLEX,$regex) | foreach {$_.groups[1].value}


$VPLEX_Clusters | Out-File F:\Scripts\healthcheck\Vplex.txt
(gc F:\Scripts\healthcheck\Vplex.txt | select -Skip 5) | sc F:\Scripts\healthcheck\cluster1.txt

$Vcluster1 = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("F:\Scripts\healthcheck\cluster1.txt")

$html = $Vcluster1 | % {
  $cluster = $_ -split ' +'
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Clustername' = $cluster[0]
    'Cluster ID'  = [int]$cluster[1]
    'State'       = $cluster[2]
    'Health'      = $cluster[3]
    'Connected'   = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[4])
    'Expelled'    = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[5])
    'Local-com'   = $cluster[6]
  }
} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment 

$html | Out-File F:\Scripts\healthcheck\test.html
Invoke-Expression F:\Scripts\healthcheck\test.html
```

This is the text file (cluster1.txt) that is read from:
[image]

And Here is the final output, as you can see only producing the first line.
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using ConvertTo-HTML instead of trying to format your own HTML? Something like `$VPLEX_Clusters | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File F:\Scripts\healthcheck\test.html`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician The problem is that the output seems to come from a Linux host (`plink` is a commandline SSH client), so it's a string "table", not PowerShell objects.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is correct. Although I was thinking maybe I can replace the spaces with commas and create a CSV file.  Then I could use ConvertFrom-CSV to automatically create the html table. Would that make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you just want to keep the plaintext table, not create an actual (HTML-)table. If that's the case you can simply put `$VPLEX_Clusters` in `<pre>` tags without the string replacements:

```
...
$VPLEX_Clusters = [regex]::Matches($VPLEX, $regex) | % {$_.groups[1].value}
"<pre>$VPLEX_Clusters</pre>" | Out-File 'F:\Scripts\healthcheck\test.html'
```

If you want to create an actual `<table>` I'd suggest to extract just the data lines without the headers, split each line into an array and build custom objects from them:

```
$VPLEX_Clusters = @"
cluster-1  1  ok  ok  True  False  ok
cluster-2  2  ok  ok  True  False  ok
"@ -split "`n"

$VPLEX_Clusters | % {
  $cluster = $_ -split ' +'
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Clustername' = $cluster[0]
    'Cluster ID'  = [int]$cluster[1]
    'State'       = $cluster[2]
    'Health'      = $cluster[3]
    'Connected'   = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[4])
    'Expelled'    = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[5])
    'Local-com'   = $cluster[6]
  }
} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

---

**Edit:** Don't use intermediate files unless you have to (hint: in this case you don't). Replace this:

```
$VPLEX_Clusters | Out-File F:\Scripts\healthcheck\Vplex.txt
(gc F:\Scripts\healthcheck\Vplex.txt | select -Skip 5) | sc F:\Scripts\healthcheck\cluster1.txt

$Vcluster1 = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("F:\Scripts\healthcheck\cluster1.txt")
```

with this:

```
$Vcluster1 = $VPLEX_Clusters -split "`r`n" | select -Skip 5 |
             ? { $_ -notmatch '^\s*$' }
```

Also note that `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment` creates only an HTML *fragment* (just a table, to be precise), not an entire HTML page. If you want an entire HTML page: remove the parameter `-Fragment`.

---

**Edit2:** The object properties are specified as hashtables, whose elements don't have a particular order. If you want the columns in a particular order, you could pipe the loop output through a `select` statement with the properties in the order you want:

```
$html = $Vcluster1 | % {
  $cluster = $_ -split ' +'
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Clustername' = $cluster[0]
    'Cluster ID'  = [int]$cluster[1]
    'State'       = $cluster[2]
    'Health'      = $cluster[3]
    'Connected'   = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[4])
    'Expelled'    = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[5])
    'Local-com'   = $cluster[6]
  }
} | select 'Clustername', 'Cluster ID', 'State', 'Health', 'Connected',
           'Expelled', 'Local-com' |
    ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you could also specify the properties hashtable as an [`ordered` hashtable](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/12/11/pshell-order.aspx):

```
$html = $Vcluster1 | % {
  $cluster = $_ -split ' +'
  $hash = [ordered]@{
    'Clustername' = $cluster[0]
    'Cluster ID'  = [int]$cluster[1]
    'State'       = $cluster[2]
    'Health'      = $cluster[3]
    'Connected'   = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[4])
    'Expelled'    = [convert]::ToBoolean($cluster[5])
    'Local-com'   = $cluster[6]
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $hash
} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Comment: It needs to be html because it is part of a large report with tables and colors etc that gets emailed. 

I'm a little confused but think this is the right track. I've cut the headers off and separated the two remaining lines into separate variables. It prints them out within the table now but I can only figure out how to use 1 line. How can I add both lines to the table?

Comment: @RichT The second code sample should already produce a complete HTML table with both lines.

Comment: It seems to only use the first line from the output and ignores the second, I posted the new complete code above along with the output.

Comment: @RichT You need the lines as a string array not as a single string (which is what `ReadAllText()` returns). See updated answer.

Comment: Great! works perfect now thank you. Just out of curiosity why is the final output in a different order than the original (starts with Cluster ID instead of Clustername)?